# Agglomerative Ward's linkage method using R/python

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

I am using R to do a hierarchical cluster analysis using the Ward's squared euclidean distance. I have a matrix of 60 columns(stations) and 221 rows(wavelength values in float), the first row contain the header(stations' names). I want to find similarities between the stations. I am using the following codes but it does not give me an explicit result (found this on the internet):

```
Rrn<-read.table("RRN.txt", header =T, dec=",")
hc <- hclust(dist(Rrn), "ave")
plot(hc)
plot(hc, hang = -1)

hc <- hclust(dist(Rrn)^2, "ward")
memb <- cutree(hc, k = 10)
cent <- NULL
for(k in 1:10){cent <- rbind(cent, colMeans(Rrn[memb == k, , drop = FALSE]))}
hc1 <- hclust(dist(cent)^2, method = "ward", members = table(memb))
opar <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(hc,  labels = FALSE, hang = -1, main = "Original Tree")
plot(hc1, labels = FALSE, hang = -1, main = "Re-start from 10 clusters")
```

I also want the names of my stations to appear on the dendrogram but cant find a simple way to do it. I would be grateful if this could also be done using PYTHON.

Comment: please include a reproducible example or a link to your data

Comment: Did you look at scikit-learn?

Comment: I have already standardised my data. I ve tried scikit also but could not extract the information i need. From my data i want to group those stations which are similar. I just cant figure out the codes.